# "3 files to edit" after quit from editing multiple files in Vim

Tags: multiple-files

I open vim with three files: `vim a.txt b.txt c.txt`. Then:

1. edit a.txt, save it by `:w`, switch to b.txt by `:n`.
2. edit b.txt, save it by `:w`, switch to c.txt by `:n`.
3. edit c.txt, save it by `:w`, and quit vim session by `:q`.

After I quit, terminal showed a message of "3 files to edit". My question is: What's wrong with my editing process? How to turn off this annoying message?

Comment: I would go by `vim *.txt` `:wn` `:wn` `:wq` and I do not have such an error unless there are unsaved files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's wrong with my editing process?

Nothing. Vim likes to talk and, in fact, that message is written **before**
you actually start editing your files, as can be confirmed if you issue `gvim`
instead of `vim`.

Another clear, unambiguous way to confirm it:

```
strace -o vimStrace vim a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

Do what you want with Vim and then close it. Now have a look at the trace file.
The first `write` call is (the English version of)

```
write(1, "3 Dateien zum Editieren\n", 24) = 24
```

> How to turn off this annoying message?

If your Vim version is recent enough, invoking it with
`--not-a-term` should solve it,
as [statox already mentioned](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26667).

In my system, although `--not-a-term` is available, it still does not implement
that functionality:

```
--not-a-term    Tells Vim that the user knows that the input and/or output is
        not connected to a terminal.  This will avoid the warning and
        the two second delay that would happen.
        Also avoids the "Reading from stdin..." message.
        {not in Vi}
```

And as the syscall shows, the message is written to file descriptor 1,
i.e. **stdout**.
Since **stdout** is also used to edit the files, the only reasonable ways to
suppress the message would be to turn to Gvim,

```
gvim a.txt b.txt c.txt > /dev/null
```

or explore the client-server capability of Vim. Both look overkill.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't say that there is anything wrong with your editing process I think it's just vim normal behavior.

For what I can say it comes from [these lines](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b5ed266037dea49024e00c4e1f9c89f3a9ebaa60/src/main.c#L368-L372):

```
// This message comes before term inits, but after setting "silent_mode"
// when the input is not a tty. Omit the message with --not-a-term.
if (GARGCOUNT > 1 && !silent_mode && !is_not_a_term())
    printf(_("%d files to edit\n"), GARGCOUNT);
```

So using `vim --not-a-term` should fix that, here is what the doc says [`:h --not-a-term`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#--not-a-term):

```
                            *--not-a-term*
--not-a-term    Tells Vim that the user knows that the input and/or output is
        not connected to a terminal.  This will avoid the warning and
        the two second delay that would happen.
        Also avoids the "Reading from stdin..." message.
        Also avoids the "N files to edit" message.
```

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Isn't that the expected behavior? I have the same message when I use Vim and I don't have other `$TERM` related issues

Comment: Ah yes you’re right for some reason i thought the message went away /facepalm

Comment: I'm, like, freaking out man. If you had told me that "X files to edit" always shows up after you exit Vim I would have called you a dirty liar. How could I never have noticed this before?  (Probably because it doesn't always show up. ;) I see it in Cygwin but not Ubuntu in WSL...the only platforms available to me at this moment. I'm still kinda freaking out, though, that I hardly noticed how prevalent it is in Cygwin. And why Cyg but not Ubuntu/WSL? Must investigate.)